# Turned on IIS in windows features but can't start it either using search->inetmgr or administrative tools

Tags: iis

I installed Windows 7 Ultimate on a machine. I turned on IIS using turn windows features on or off. See below:
[image]

But I can't start IIS! If I type IIS manager in search window, I don't get any result. If I browse to administrative tool, IIS is not there! See below:
[image]

I have also rebooted several times. Please help.

Also did iisreset.

```
C:\Windows\system32>iisreset

Attempting stop...
Internet services successfully stopped
Attempting start...
Internet services successfully restarted

C:\Windows\system32>
```

There is no iis.msc under c:\windows\system32\inetsrv

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>dir *.msc
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is BA56-4174

 Directory of C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv

File Not Found
```

**Fixed it. Hadn't turned on IIS->Web Management Tools -> IIS Management Console.**

[image]

Comment: solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't write comments yet :( - so sorry its in an answer space.
if you open up a dos shell, and type iisreset, does anything happen?  I ask to see if IIS is infact running.  Either way, try uninstalling then reinstalling IIS.

If you want we can chat in a chat room on here....

Comment: ok so you ran iisreset - it is in fact running and you were able to get IIS to start.  Maybe now try to uninstall and reinstall it?

Comment: In my case on windows 2008r2, I could run iisreset but could not run the management (inetmgr). I had to install the iis management tools. To run iis manager, run the command "inetmgr"