# Error : The mbstring extension is missing from

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, mbstring

Whenever I try to enter my phpMyAdmin, it gives me this error:

```
The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
```

I have already searched the solution and add `extension=php_mbstring.dll` in my `php.ini` file. But still doesn't fix it.

Comment: did you restart PHP

Comment: PHP means Apache ? I have restart Apache already

Comment: no, PHP mean PHP, however often restarting Apache can have the same effect.  As PHP runs inside of the apache server.  In this context Apache is the environment, PHP is just a program that runs in that environment.

Comment: then check the phpinfo(), as mentioned by @Ms.KV.  In other words create a file named, info.php.  with this code in it `<?php phpinfo();` then run it in the browser, and search for mbstring.  It may not also hurt to check for PHP errors, and in the apache startup log.

Comment: I followed `Click Start, click Run, type IISReset, and then click OK.` this process for restart the PHP. But got error again `Windows cannot find IISReset'

Answer (score 0):

You only enabled `mbstring` by `extension=php_mbstring.dll` in php.ini.But you should also install it in php configuration.Check your info.php file that contain `phpinfo();` function for providing the installation extention in your php.

Comment: is not the php.ini, the config file for PHP.

Comment: @raff Please follow this step mentioned by me and check.

Comment: First create `info.php` and call this function `phpinfo();`into it.After that run this `info.php` on browser,it will show a page that contain all intalled and enabled extention.

Comment: @Ms.KV...`mbstring` is enabled . I found 
`Multibyte Support enabled` for `mbstring`

Comment: Ok. Please have look into this post.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192401/turned-on-iis-in-windows-features-but-cant-start-it-either-using-search-inetmg)